# xml deserialization <string> tag

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

I wrote web service using System.ServiceModel System.ServiceModel.Web System.ServiceModel.Activation namespaces.

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
        [OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = Routing.GetClientRoute, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        string GetClientNameById(string Id);
```

I described data with this class:

```
[XmlRoot("ServiceXmlReply")]
    public class ServiceXmlReply
    {
        [XmlElement]
        public string Name;
    }
```

Problem is with respond, which i receive from service. It looks like this:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<string>
<ServiceXmlReply xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"
xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">
<Name>Igor<Name>
<ServiceXmlReply>
</string>"
```

As can you see there not supposed to be "string" tag, but it is. Because of it i can't deserialize respond and get data.

Class is same on server and client's side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your operation contract defines that the response of GetClientNameById is of type string. So what happens is that the contents of your return type string is a serialized xml.

To get this working, you should is:

1. change the return type of your operation to ServiceXmlReply or
2. abandon the use of ServiceXmlReply. Use string in stead on service and client side.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
The problem is that that method returns XML code of class as string. I can't just convert it to my type.
Problem is with additional serialization on my thought. Does anyone know how to set it off?

Comment: I thinked one more time and found solution. You was totally right. I just changed my class, so it returned whole my class and don't xml document. It created correct xml by itself.
I'm happy now. Thank You!!